# Data sub-setting using strings including sign greater than or less than

Tags: r

I would like to generate a full non-duplicate (row wise and column wise) combination of strings that contain instructions as greater than and less than (possibly adding other mathematical sign).

How can I do it? Please see below example including partial solution, which however is missing the ">" and "<" sign, so basically the variable name, here in this example named as `a:e` plus the sign for sub-setting in case variable is less or greater than 0.

The `comb` object includes the variables including the desired sign for sub-setting.

```
comb <- data.frame(in1=c("a > 0","b > 0","c > 0","d > 0","e > 0"),
                   in2=c("a < 0","b < 0","c < 0","d < 0","e < 0"))

comb.vars <- with(comb, expand.grid(in1,in2, stringsAsFactors=F))
comb.vars <- rbind(data.frame(data.frame(Var3="y > 0"),comb.vars),
                   data.frame(data.frame(Var3="y < 0"),comb.vars));
comb.vars
```

This does not give the desired outcome since in the same line it can occur the same variable shows opposing sign, example: `y > 0 a > 0 a < 0` in first line and also line 7 gives `y > 0 b > 0 b < 0`

```
dup <- apply(comb.vars, 1, function(x) length(which(duplicated(x)))>0)
remdup1 <- comb.vars[!dup, ]

onlyvars <- apply(remdup1, 2, function(x) substr(x, 1, regexpr("\\>", x)-1))
# remove row-wise duplicats
dup <- apply(onlyvars, 1, function(x) length(which(duplicated(x)))>0)
remdup2 <- onlyvars[!dup, ]
# remove among rows duplicates
uniq <- remdup1[!duplicated(apply(remdup2, 1, function(row) paste(sort(row), collapse=""))), ] 
uniq
```

Base `r` solution required only.

Comment: You explicitly remove them when you choose to subset `onlvars[!dup,]`, i.e., you are preserving the frame where you explicitly cut them out from the string. Perhaps your second `remdup` should be `remdup <- remdup[!dup,]`. After that, I'm not sure why you need the `uniq` expression.

Comment: `remdup[!duplicated(apply(remdup, 1, function(row) paste(sort(row), collapse=""))), ] ` here in this line I'm checking the unique combination also row wise, if I include signs this won't do it.

Comment: `opposing signs "<" and same variable ">"` ... do you mean `same variable "c"`?

Comment: @r2evans in fact solution is still not found after all, apologies.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you are looking for.  does `expand.grid(data.frame(t(comb)))` help?

Comment: @Onyambu, it seems to give the desired output, but still need to check. If you wish in meantime to post it as answer and I will accept once this is confirmed. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the number of times the first character is repeated across a row and then only keep rows where the values where the value does not duplicate.

Using `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)
comb.vars %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(
        repvals = sum(duplicated(str_extract(c(Var1, Var2, Var3), "^\\w")))
    ) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    filter(repvals == 0) %>% 
    select(-repvals)
```

Returns:

```
# A tibble: 40 × 3
   Var3  Var1  Var2 
   <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1 y > 0 b > 0 a < 0
 2 y > 0 c > 0 a < 0
 3 y > 0 d > 0 a < 0
 4 y > 0 e > 0 a < 0
 5 y > 0 a > 0 b < 0
 6 y > 0 c > 0 b < 0
 7 y > 0 d > 0 b < 0
 8 y > 0 e > 0 b < 0
 9 y > 0 a > 0 c < 0
10 y > 0 b > 0 c < 0
# ℹ 30 more rows
```

A base R version to do the same:

```
comb.vars$rep = apply(comb.vars, 1, function(x) {
        sum(duplicated(sapply(regmatches(x, gregexec("^\\w", x)), function(x) x[[1]])))
})
comb.vars <- comb.vars[comb.vars$rep == 0, ]
```

Comment: thanks, would you happen to have also base `r` solution at hand? I cannot now adapt it further beyond the example :)

Comment: @Maximilian, I just added a base r solution. I'm sure it could be more elegant, but it works to do the same thing as the `dplyr` version.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you want to get the mutually exclusive regions. In that case you need to transpose your comb dataset before you expand them to a grid.

```
expand.grid(c(data.frame(t(comb)), list(c('y > 0', 'y < 0'))))

     X1    X2    X3    X4    X5  Var6
1  a > 0 b > 0 c > 0 d > 0 e > 0 y > 0
2  a < 0 b > 0 c > 0 d > 0 e > 0 y > 0
3  a > 0 b < 0 c > 0 d > 0 e > 0 y > 0
4  a < 0 b < 0 c > 0 d > 0 e > 0 y > 0
5  a > 0 b > 0 c < 0 d > 0 e > 0 y > 0
6  a < 0 b > 0 c < 0 d > 0 e > 0 y > 0
7  a > 0 b < 0 c < 0 d > 0 e > 0 y > 0
8  a < 0 b < 0 c < 0 d > 0 e > 0 y > 0
9  a > 0 b > 0 c > 0 d < 0 e > 0 y > 0
10 a < 0 b > 0 c > 0 d < 0 e > 0 y > 0
11 a > 0 b < 0 c > 0 d < 0 e > 0 y > 0
12 a < 0 b < 0 c > 0 d < 0 e > 0 y > 0
13 a > 0 b > 0 c < 0 d < 0 e > 0 y > 0
14 a < 0 b > 0 c < 0 d < 0 e > 0 y > 0
15 a > 0 b < 0 c < 0 d < 0 e > 0 y > 0
16 a < 0 b < 0 c < 0 d < 0 e > 0 y > 0
17 a > 0 b > 0 c > 0 d > 0 e < 0 y > 0
18 a < 0 b > 0 c > 0 d > 0 e < 0 y > 0
19 a > 0 b < 0 c > 0 d > 0 e < 0 y > 0
20 a < 0 b < 0 c > 0 d > 0 e < 0 y > 0
21 a > 0 b > 0 c < 0 d > 0 e < 0 y > 0
22 a < 0 b > 0 c < 0 d > 0 e < 0 y > 0
23 a > 0 b < 0 c < 0 d > 0 e < 0 y > 0
24 a < 0 b < 0 c < 0 d > 0 e < 0 y > 0
25 a > 0 b > 0 c > 0 d < 0 e < 0 y > 0
26 a < 0 b > 0 c > 0 d < 0 e < 0 y > 0
27 a > 0 b < 0 c > 0 d < 0 e < 0 y > 0
28 a < 0 b < 0 c > 0 d < 0 e < 0 y > 0
29 a > 0 b > 0 c < 0 d < 0 e < 0 y > 0
30 a < 0 b > 0 c < 0 d < 0 e < 0 y > 0
31 a > 0 b < 0 c < 0 d < 0 e < 0 y > 0
32 a < 0 b < 0 c < 0 d < 0 e < 0 y > 0
33 a > 0 b > 0 c > 0 d > 0 e > 0 y < 0
34 a < 0 b > 0 c > 0 d > 0 e > 0 y < 0
35 a > 0 b < 0 c > 0 d > 0 e > 0 y < 0
36 a < 0 b < 0 c > 0 d > 0 e > 0 y < 0
37 a > 0 b > 0 c < 0 d > 0 e > 0 y < 0
38 a < 0 b > 0 c < 0 d > 0 e > 0 y < 0
39 a > 0 b < 0 c < 0 d > 0 e > 0 y < 0
40 a < 0 b < 0 c < 0 d > 0 e > 0 y < 0
41 a > 0 b > 0 c > 0 d < 0 e > 0 y < 0
42 a < 0 b > 0 c > 0 d < 0 e > 0 y < 0
43 a > 0 b < 0 c > 0 d < 0 e > 0 y < 0
44 a < 0 b < 0 c > 0 d < 0 e > 0 y < 0
45 a > 0 b > 0 c < 0 d < 0 e > 0 y < 0
46 a < 0 b > 0 c < 0 d < 0 e > 0 y < 0
47 a > 0 b < 0 c < 0 d < 0 e > 0 y < 0
48 a < 0 b < 0 c < 0 d < 0 e > 0 y < 0
49 a > 0 b > 0 c > 0 d > 0 e < 0 y < 0
50 a < 0 b > 0 c > 0 d > 0 e < 0 y < 0
51 a > 0 b < 0 c > 0 d > 0 e < 0 y < 0
52 a < 0 b < 0 c > 0 d > 0 e < 0 y < 0
53 a > 0 b > 0 c < 0 d > 0 e < 0 y < 0
54 a < 0 b > 0 c < 0 d > 0 e < 0 y < 0
55 a > 0 b < 0 c < 0 d > 0 e < 0 y < 0
56 a < 0 b < 0 c < 0 d > 0 e < 0 y < 0
57 a > 0 b > 0 c > 0 d < 0 e < 0 y < 0
58 a < 0 b > 0 c > 0 d < 0 e < 0 y < 0
59 a > 0 b < 0 c > 0 d < 0 e < 0 y < 0
60 a < 0 b < 0 c > 0 d < 0 e < 0 y < 0
61 a > 0 b > 0 c < 0 d < 0 e < 0 y < 0
62 a < 0 b > 0 c < 0 d < 0 e < 0 y < 0
63 a > 0 b < 0 c < 0 d < 0 e < 0 y < 0
64 a < 0 b < 0 c < 0 d < 0 e < 0 y < 0
```

---

Or you could start by simply having the elements in the correct order, ie

```
comb1 = list(c('a > 0', 'a < 0'), 
             c('b > 0', 'b < 0'), 
             c('c > 0', 'c < 0'), 
             c('d > 0', 'd < 0'),
             c('e > 0', 'e < 0'),
             c('y > 0', 'y < 0'))
 expand.grid(comb1)
```